# I have udisks2 but no rules file to edit

Tags: udev, udisks

I wanted to add some rules to `udisks2` by adding them to `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-udisks2.rules` as suggested [in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214646/how-to-configure-the-default-automount-location) [various](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udisks) [sources](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E41138/html/ch07s03.html). However, this file does not exist on my system in that folder. I have confirmed that udisks2 is installed and active, but I do not have that rules file.

Should I create it myself or is it located somewhere else? I'm running Raspbian Jessie on an Rpi3.

Comment: Create it yourself...

Comment: Shouldn't it be there by default?

Comment: No. Files in `/etc/udev/rules.d` are rules written by the admin.

Comment: Thank you! I'm a novice, so maybe it will be helpful for other novice users if you'd make an answer so this piece of information will become clear. I haven't encountered any documentation that says that file isn't placed there by default (I guess all documentation assumes the user has created that file)

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev Why would any documentation mention that some file (insert a million custom rules names here) is not there ?

Comment: For a novice, especially in rules, it is not apparent that this file has to be created if one is searching for ways to add `udisks2` rules. Even if the administrator should write the rules. I was expecting `udisks2` to set up a rules files there (maybe blank) for me to edit. The materials I found all assume that this file has been created already as they don't explicitly say this file has to be created first. That was the source of my confusion. I'll answer the question myself. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: No problem. Please do answer it if you feel like it. As I said, it is an arbitrary file name. They could have called it `99-iwannagotothebeach.rules` and it'd be a perfectly valid name for a `udev` rule.